# Not getting NSMetaDataQuery update Notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsmetadataquery, icloud-documents

I have the following code:

```
// Main thread
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self,
    selector:#selector(queryDidFinish),
    name:NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object:nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self,
    selector:#selector(queryDidUpdate),
    name:NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object:nil)
```

and also:

```
private var query = NSMetadataQuery() // Class level

func queryCloud()
{
    // Called on main thread
    query.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]
    query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%K like '*.jpg')",
                                    NSMetadataItemFSNameKey) 
    queryHot.start()
}

@objc func queryDidFinish(notification: NSNotification)
{
    print("This gets called once on main thread")
    print("and the query can be read")
}

@objc func queryDidUpdate(notification: NSNotification)
{
    print("This does not get called")
}
```

So, the above "used to work", across two devices. Now, neither device gets the queryDidUpdate() call. I've tried deleting the app, turning cloud permissions on and off, signing in and out of iCloud, rebooting the devices. Both devices can read their "frozen" cloud, but no data is propagated and no live phase notifications are delivered. I did do some heavy testing (transferring hundreds of MB of pictures) between the two devices for a few days. And now, things have stopped working.

The cloud tokens for each device are completely different, but are stable.
Using UIDocument to store into the cloud.

Am I missing something? Is there something I need to reset in iCloud? Is there a status I can check somewhere?

I don't want to change the app bundle ID as a way to get unstuck ... I'd like to find the underlying problem.
Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay, but the iCloud on the device was in a state. Ultimately, I turned off and on "iCloud Drive" (which is different than just signing on to iCloud). After putting back settings for the app, everything started to work.